# Return 0 and not NULL when record is not found using left outer join

Tags: mysql, join, count, outer-join

I have two tables. My query should return the following:

```
AUT  | 0
```

but it doesn't return anything. Tried the following below, but nothing works.

```sql
select substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) as ko_tun, ifnull(count(s.id),0) 
from study_entitlement s
left outer join graduation_status g on g.study_entitlement_id = s.id
where g.graduation_status_date between str_to_date('01.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') 
  and str_to_date('31.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
and substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) = 'AUT'
group by substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3);
```

```sql
select substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) as ko_tun, count(s.id)+0 
from study_entitlement s
left outer join graduation_status g on g.study_entitlement_id = s.id
where g.graduation_status_date between str_to_date('01.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') 
  and str_to_date('31.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
and substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) = 'AUT'
group by substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3);
```

```sql
select substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) as ko_tun, COALESCE(count(s.id),0) 
from study_entitlement s
left outer join graduation_status g on g.study_entitlement_id = s.id 
where substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) = 'AUT'
and g.graduation_status_date between str_to_date('01.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') 
  and str_to_date('31.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
group by substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3);
```

Comment: Please format your code with the editor so it's easier to tell which is which.

Comment: Are you certain that group `AUT` actually exists in your data set?  You might need to go the route of using a calendar table here.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem here, in that both of your selected columns are in your base table and not the outer joined table. What do you mean that nothing works? I'm assuming the three queries are all different attempts at the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Generically, since your code is rather messy:

```
SELECT
    TblA.column1,
    TblA.column2,
    TblB.column3
FROM
    a AS TblA
LEFT JOIN
    b AS TblB
    ON TblA.column4 = TblB.column4
```

Will result in `NULL` for `column3` wherever the tables do not join (or the value in `column3` is `NULL`).

Therefore, you could add an `IF` statement to change that:

```
SELECT
    TblA.column1,
    TblA.column2,
    IF(TblB.column3 IS NULL, 0, TblB.column3) AS column3
FROM
    a AS TblA
LEFT JOIN
    b AS TblB
    ON TblA.column4 = TblB.column4
```

Which says that "if column3 is null, then set it to 0, otherwise, return the column value."

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the filtering criteria on the outer table from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join. Otherwise you are implicitly converting to an `INNER JOIN`.

Something like this should work for you:

```
select substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) as ko_tun, 
  count(g.study_entitlement_id)
from study_entitlement s
left outer join graduation_status g on g.study_entitlement_id = s.id 
  and g.graduation_status_date between str_to_date('01.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y') 
    and str_to_date('31.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
where substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3) = 'AUT'
group by substr(s.initial_group_code,1,3);
```

Comment: Thanks a million Ike Walker.I actually did have the filtering criteria at the start on the ON -clause, but failed to notice that I was counting the wrong column. So thanks again :)